# Can't apply multiple transformation to UIImageView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't find out why my transformations are not being applied to a UIImageView in Xamarin iOS.

Here's the code:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = new CGAffineTransform();

transform.Rotate((float)Math.PI / 2);
transform.Scale(0.8f, 0.8f);

this.imageViewOverlay = new UIImageView
{ 
    ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center,
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
    Opaque = false,
    Frame = new CGRect(0,0,this.View.Bounds.Width, this.View.Bounds.Height),
    Transform = transform
};
```

The way I was doing it before used to be like

```
Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)Math.PI / 2)
```

But unfortunately when you want to use it twice, the second one is clearing the transformation before.

I'm using

Xamarin.iOS:
Version: 8.6.0.41 (Business Edition)

Operating System:
Mac OS X 10.10.3

XCode: Version 6.3.1 (6D1002)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `CGAffineTransform` is empty (all 0`0`), default for a struct, and *not* an identity transform, on top of which you can construct something. IOW that makes all subsequent calls (math ops) return an empty one.

You can either start with a non-empty transform, e.g.

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation((float)Math.PI / 2);
transform.Scale(0.8f, 0.8f);
```

or you can start with an identity transform, e.g.

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity ();
transform.Rotate ((nfloat) Math.PI / 2);
transform.Scale ((nfloat) 0.8f, (nfloat) 0.8f);
```